# Convert Horizontal Navigation Bar into Vertical Navigation Bar in Word Press Theme(redxunlite)

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins, navbar

Convert Horizontal Navigation Bar into Vertical Navigation Bar in Word Press Theme(redxunlite)

**HTML**

```
<nav id="redxunlite-navigation" class="main-navigation animated nav-down swingInX" role="navigation">

    <div class="container">
        <a class="blog-text" href="http://10.65.2.15/tsg/" rel="home">TSG Client Management System</a>

        <ul class="mobile-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-35" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-5 current_page_item menu-item-35"><a href="http://10.65.2.15/tsg/">MTS Clients</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-53" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-53"><a href="http://10.65.2.15/tsg/ncss/">NCSS Clients</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-34" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-34"><a href="http://10.65.2.15/tsg/article/">Inventory Sheet</a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="main-menu">
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-5 current_page_item menu-item-35"><a href="http://10.65.2.15/tsg/">MTS Clients</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-53"><a href="http://10.65.2.15/tsg/ncss/">NCSS Clients</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-34"><a href="http://10.65.2.15/tsg/article/">Inventory Sheet</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="toggles">
            <div class="nav-toggle toggle">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- /toggles -->
        <div class="clearfix"></div>

    </div>
</nav>
```

Here is the HTML applied on the relevant nav bar .please help me in this regards so we can manage it

**CSS**

```
.main-navigation {
  color: #111;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  position: fixed;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  top: 0;
  /* transition: top 0.3s ease-in-out; */
  min-height: 64px;
  -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease 0;
  -moz-transition: all 150ms ease 0;
  -o-transition: all 150ms ease 0;
  -ms-transition: all 150ms ease 0;
  transition: all 150ms ease 0;
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup,
main, nav, section, summary {
  display: block;
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup,
main, menu, nav, section, summary {
  display: block;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

article, aside, footer, header, hgroup, main, nav, section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.6;
  overflow-x: none;
  font-family: Roboto, Georgia;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  color: #424242;
  font-weight: 400;
  background: #fff;
}

body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

How to do vertical Navigation by CSS.so we can convert horizontal nav bar into vertical nav bar in wordpress theme

Comment: You would probably need to change the structure of the document (HTML) to achieve a vertical navigation bar.

Comment: @HåvardGeithus but in wordpress we are unable to change the html,so it is possible to acheive it via CSS.

Comment: Could you also post the basic HTML structure of the page? For example, by going to your website in the browser, then via Devtools or "View source" copy the HTML and remove the non-relevant parts.

Comment: @HåvardGeithus added

Comment: Sorry for not specifying this, but we need some more context around the `<nav>`, for example: if your structure is similar to this; https://jsfiddle.net/rksjdvmk/ where you have the `<nav>` at the same level as your content `<div>`, then you can use those as columns in your layout.